Use Selected Field Parameter in Calculated Column
I'm using field parameters to select the time value for the x-axis of my visual. This works great, but some of the values in the selected column are null/blank, and I don't want a blank value displayed in my visual. I can filter the visual on a column and remove blanks, but as soon as I switch the time value, that filter is no longer valid because it doesn't reference the new selection.
I'm trying to create a dynamic flag to use to filter the data, and I'm having trouble with it (also not completely sure it's possible).
If I create a flag with the actual name of the column selected in the field parameter like this:
Time Slicer Flag = IF(ISBLANK('Dates'[Year]), 0, 1)

I get what I want: A 0 for blank and 1 otherwise.
So far, I've tried this to use the field parameter slicer column value ('Dates'[Year] is selected):
Time Slicer Flag2 = IF(ISBLANK(MAX('Time Slicer'[Time Slicer Fields])), 0, 1)

This doesn't work, and everything ends up as 1. Is there a step I'm missing perhaps?

Hi as per Microsoft It's now possible, refer this link

